# $A.getCallback error says property undefined

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

Could someone explain what is happening within these lines in detail, as I am getting an error pointed to these lines. Also please advise on any fixes possible. thanks

```
approvePaymentRequest: function(component) {
        this.submitAction(component, "c.approvePaymentRequest");
      },
      submitAction: function(component, methodName) {
        component.set("v.disabled", true);
        this.enqueueAction(component, methodName, { paymentRequestId: component.get("v.paymentRequest.Id") },
          function() {
            var refreshComponentEvent = $A.get("e.c:refreshComponentEvent");
            refreshComponentEvent.setParams({ "event": "paymentRequestUpdated" });
            refreshComponentEvent.fire();
            component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord(true);
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
          },
          function() {
            component.set("v.disabled", false);
          }
        );
      },
```

APEX

```
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void approvePaymentRequest(Id paymentRequestId) {
    Payment_Request__c paymentRequest = [SELECT Id, Status__c, Coop_Campaign__c FROM Payment_Request__c WHERE Id = :paymentRequestId];
    paymentRequest.Approved_Date__c = Date.today();
    paymentRequest.Status__c = 'Approved';
    update paymentRequest;

    List<Coop_Campaign__c> coopCampaigns = [SELECT Id, Payment_Status__c FROM Coop_Campaign__c WHERE Id = :paymentRequest.Coop_Campaign__c AND (Payment_Status__c = 'Pending Finance Approval')];
    if (coopCampaigns.size() > 0) {
      Coop_Campaign__c coopCampaign = coopCampaigns[0];
      List<Payment_Request__c> paymentRequests = [SELECT Id FROM Payment_Request__c WHERE Coop_Campaign__c = :coopCampaign.Id AND (Status__c = 'Pending Finance Approval')];
      if (paymentRequests.size() == 0 && coopCampaign != null) {
        coopCampaign.Payment_Status__c = 'Approved';
        update coopCampaign;
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is the error message I get [image]

Comment: In your `.cmp` file do you have any component which has `aura:id='recordLoader'`. Your code is trying to look for that component in line `component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord(true);` and is not able to find it?

Comment: @manjit5190 the cmp file does not have a component with that id. Not sure why the developer is referring to a component which does not exist.

Comment: It can be that this component is extending a template. You can check it in top level tag, if not I would suggest reviewing the code with the developer.

Comment: @manjit5190 Could you please elaborate when you say this component is extending a template. The developer is long gone from the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord(true);
```

In the above code, when you get the undefined error , you need to make sure that whichever variables throws undefined error, is assigned a value to it.

In this case, `component.find("recordLoader")`

recordLoader would normally be an [assigned ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm) of what would probably be another aura component in the template of the JS file.

If you are not familiar with what might be going on I would suggest you take a look at [Calling Component Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods.htm).

Comment: Thanks @glls, it is working as ofnow.